# Need email Notification service using smtp,using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to implement Nodemailer for sending one or bulk emails but facing trouble to handle when there is a failure in sending email for eg. Email Address not found. I need a list of these bounced emails and other such failures and insert them into the DB,after trying to send the email twice.

Below is my code:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var smtpConfig = nodemailer.createTransport(
    {
        host: hostname,
        port: port,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        },
        logger: false,
        debug: false
    },
    {
        headers: [],
        priority: "normal"
    }
);

function sendMailnew() {
    const mailOptions = {       
        from: "email.com,
        to: "sjdhf@jhdf.com",
        subject: "my testing emails new",
        html: "my testing email",
        dsn: {
            id: "123",
            return: "HEADERS",
            notify: ["failure", "delay"],
            recipient: "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    };
    smtpConfig.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("mail sent");
        }
    });
}

sendMailnew();
```

I am using gmail SMTP. Please Help.Thanks!Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: The bounced emails aren't retrievable when sending mails, you have to get them later, from your email propvider, or by implementing a bounces detection system.

Comment: @Veve Can you provide me with some bounce detection system that i can implement with this

Comment: No sorry, it's not an easy task. What I can suggest you is to use a real emails provider with this functionnality instead of gmail, which will certainly block you quickly if you send bulk emails.

Comment: @Veve I don't want to block bulk emails, i want to track bounced emails or failed emails and retry on that

Comment: As I said before, it really not an easy task, and quoting your question, "I am trying to implement Nodemailer for sending one or bulk emails"... Google *will* block you sooner or later. You do as you want but you'll avoid a lot of problems and headaches by using a real email provider.