# this is my nodemailer program Even if i give wrong mail in TO addrress also it is showing message sent how to rectifyy that

Tags: node.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: '*************',
    pass: '*********',
  },
});

let mailDetails = {
  from: '********',
  to: 'uuwdwuvw@', //guguygugiug
  subject: 'Test mail',
  //text: 'redeem your gift',
  html: 'redeem your coupon code ',
};

mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error Occurs');
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent successfully');
  }
});
```

this is my nodemailer program Even if i give wrong mail in TO addrress also it is showing message sent how to rectifyy that

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer itself can't tell if an email has been delivered or not. It can tell you only if the email has been sent. There's a difference between email being sent and being delivered. Detecting bounced emails is out of scope for the Nodemailer.

In order to do that you need to implement your own bounced email mechanism, probably with your own SMTP server. It's not an easy thing to do, so you should probably use some real email provider that has this functionality instead of Gmail (Google likes to block such applications).

Have a look at the similar question I've found [on GitHub](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/487) and [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504101/need-email-notification-service-using-smtp-using-nodemailer).